# Adding X to end of string with exactly 7 characters (not including commas)

Tags: excel

```
'=IF(LEN(A1)<7,A1,IF(LEN(A1)=7,A1&"X",IF(LEN(TRIM(LEFT(A1,IFERROR(FIND(",",A1)-1,0))))=7,TRIM(LEFT(A1,IFERROR(FIND(",",A1)-1,0)))&"X",TRIM(LEFT(A1,IFERROR(FIND(",",A1)-1,A1))))))
```

I'm using the above code for the following screenshot.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9GDx.jpg)

The inputs in column A have had the proper output in Column C using the formula (Thanks cybernetic.nomad) however for the entry in A6, I am getting an error for the output in C6. (The proper output should be AB123456)

Comment: so `1234567,12345678` is in one cell and you want the output in the other cell to only be: `1234567X`?

Comment: or do you want the output to be `1234567X,12345678`

Comment: And what happens with `1234567, 1234567` does it become `1234567X, 1234567X`? and what about `12345678, 1234567`?

Comment: @Scott Craner Yes output of 1234567,12345678 to only be, 1234567X

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad 1234567, 1234567  becomes 1234567X  |   12345678, 1234567 becomes 12345678

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but this seems to get you what you want:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)<7,A1,IF(LEN(A1)=7,A1&"X",IF(LEN(TRIM(LEFT(A1,IFERROR(FIND(",",A1)-1,0))))=7,TRIM(LEFT(A1,IFERROR(FIND(",",A1)-1,0)))&"X",TRIM(LEFT(A1,IFERROR(FIND(",",A1)-1,A1))))))
```

[image]

Note 1: I assumed numbers with fewer than seven digits stay the same

Edit: Updated formula, but not screen cap

Comment: Can you make it so that 12345678 outputs to 12345678?

Comment: Found the update. I've run into another problem. 1234567F = Error (#value!)

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55503442/edit) to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?